# SelectList issue (Selected value)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen

I have several DDL in a Modal Bootstrap (5) and those DDL binding with a Viewbag from the Controller, Like this:

**(Controller)**

```
ViewBag.StateID = new SelectList(db.State, "StateID", "StateDesc", events.StateID);
ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(db.Country, "CountryID", "CountryDesc",events.CountryID);
ViewBag.HotelID = new SelectList(db.Hotel, "HotelID", "HotelDesc", events.HotelID);
ViewBag.AirportID = new SelectList(db.Airport, "AirportID", "AirportDesc", events.AirportID);
ViewBag.AirlineID = new SelectList(db.Airline, "AirlineID ", "AirlineDesc", events.AirlineID);
```

My view work perfectly fine and populate the DDL and show the selected item if my code declaration is this:

**(View)**

```
@Html.DropDownList("AirlineID", String.Empty)
```

**(Javascript)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#AirlineID').attr('class', 'chosen-select form-control required');
    $('#AirportID').attr('class', 'chosen-select form-control required');
    $('#StateID').attr('class', 'chosen-select form-control required');
    $('#CountryID').attr('class', 'chosen-select form-control required');
    $('#HotelID').attr('class', 'chosen-select form-control required');
</script>
```

but, If my code is declared from this way, the Selected item don't appear or Show:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AirportID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AirportID, String.Empty, new { @class = "chosen-select form-control required" })
```

I use chosen-select class

Why is that? Missing Declaration or Code? Wrong code?

Thanks you

Comment: You cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `ViewBag` property. I strongly recommend you use view models and the strongly typed helpers but you could try `@Html.DropDownList("AirportID", null, string.Empty, new { ... })`

Comment: Work fine your solution, the declaration from AirportID  was a missing a leter, a bad edit, but why is not working of that manners? Thaks for your help.... @StephenMuecke

Comment: Sorry, Didn't understand you comment

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for my bad english... is not my native language, Why don't work this code with the Selected Value `@Html.DropDownList("CountryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryID, String.Empty, new { @class = "chosen-select form-control required" })` and the Viewbag declaration from the Controller...

Comment: OK, I will add an answer shortly to give you an explanation (and also show you the recommended approach)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks mate (your first answer work fine) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same name for both the property your binding to and the `SelectList`

```
@Html.DropDownList("CountryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryID, ...)
```

means you binding to a property named `CountryID` but in you case, `CountryID` is a `SelectList` not a value type (and a `<select>` element can only be bound to a value type.

Internally the method generates a collection of `<option>` elements and sets the `value` attribute and text. As it does so, it checks the value of the property your binding to. If the value of the property matches the value of the option then the `selected="selected"` attribute is rendered. In your case `CountryID` is not a `int` value which matches one of the `StateID` values your generating in the options so `selected="selected"` is never set on any option because the value of `CountryID` is `"System.Web.Mvc.SelectList"` (not `"1"` or `"2"` etc)

Setting the last parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is simply ignored when your binding to a property.

You can make this work by specifying `null` as the second parameter, meaning the helper falls back to using the `SelectList` as the first parameter.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CountryID", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "chosen-select form-control required" })
```

However the recommended approach is to use a view model, for example

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "Country")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a country")]
  public int CountryID { get; set; }
  public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method, initialize an instance or the view model, map your data model properties to it and assign the `SelectList` properties. Then in the view, use the strongly typed html helpers to bind to your model properties.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryID)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, Model.CountryList, "-Please select-", new { @class="..." })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryID)
```

Comment: Great Explanation... Thanks you.